# Hibernate returns rows that are not matching

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have a scheduled executor service that runs a managed query on a timer:

```
    List<Tasks> running = null;
    EntityManager em = null;
    String query = "SELECT t FROM Tasks t WHERE t.state IN (:stateList)";

    try
    {
        em = getEntityManager();
        TypedQuery<Tasks> q = em.createQuery(query, Tasks.class);
        q.setParameter("stateList", Arrays.asList(TaskState.RUNNING, TaskState.PENDING));           

        running = q.getResultList();
    }
    finally
    {
        closeEntityManager(em);
    }

    return running;
```

Another thread executes the task and sets it's state to complete and it's end time to the the execution ended. This is achieved through updating by ID, I'm not passing managed objects around.

Long after the task is completed, the query above keeps returning the task with it's state still showing as running and the end time is null.

I looked in the DB and the state is set to complete and the so is the end time.

There are no other threads that can modify the DB row.

It's almost as if the row is loaded from a cache, not the DB. This is confirmed because when I restart the application the behavior disappears.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

What's your transactional boundary?  I'm guessing it's an issue of transaction isolation, each time you run the query it should be in its own transaction.  Otherwise, the query only sees the db state at the time the transaction starts.

Comment: Does it matter? I'm closing the entitymanager after each query.

Comment: Depends on the entity manager.  Transactions happen on the db connection, so if you're not starting a new txn with each query, it could be a stale txn.